# List of Utilties Similar to Lifehacker's Texter?

Tags: windows-7

Does anybody have a list of utilities similar to LifeHacker's [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software//lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php)?

It works great except that some of the features didn't really make the leap to Windows 7.  (for instance when you try to delete anything it doesn't work), so I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I just found one that seems sufficient:

It's called [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/demo.htm) it's commercial (but free for personal use), it's actually a lot better than Texter as it works well on Mac and Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [AutoHotkey Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

```
::hi::Hello, how are you?
::imfi::I'm fine.
::cya::See ya later...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out [AlternativeTo.net](http://AlternativeTo.net). It does a good job keeping track of software alternatives, and you can filter by OS and free/pay-for. [Here's](http://alternativeto.net/software/texter/) their list of Texter alternatives.